# QtCreator и QNX

Tags: qt, unix, qtcreator, qnx

Настроил Qt Creator под QNX. Создаю новое приложение Qt Widgets. Сборка проходит нормально. Нажимаю "Запустить" - консоль выводит сообщение:

> Невозможно запустить: команда не указана.

Приложения Qt Quick собираются и запускаются, проблема только с Qt Widget. В чем может быть дело?

Сам Qt Creator работает под Windows, на QNX только запускается готовое приложение.

Comment: а откуда уверенность что сборка проходит нормально? исполняемый файл появляется где надо?

Comment: на инструментальной системе появляется

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При создании нового проекта "Qt Widgets" или "Консольное приложение Qt" в Qt Creator, по какой-то причине не создаётся автоматически механизм для установки скомпилированной программы в системе QNX.

Решение: скопировать в каталог проекта, рядом с *.pro файлом файл deployment.pri от другого проекта, который создавался с использованием Qt Quick.

В файл проекта *.pro добавить внизу строки:

```
include(deployment.pri)
qtcAddDeployment()
```

Или ещё проще, в файл проекта *.pro добавить следующие строки:

```
unix:!android {
isEmpty(target.path) {
    qnx {
        target.path = /usr/local/bin
    } else {
        target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
    }
    export(target.path)
}
INSTALLS += target
}
export(INSTALLS)
```

или даже ещё проще:

```
target.path = /usr/local/bin
INSTALLS += target
export(INSTALLS)
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно было в .pro-файл проекта добавить следующие строки:

> INSTALLS += target
>   target.path = /tmp/$$QMAKE_TARGET

т.е. вручную прописать путь установки приложения на целевую машину.